# What is the name of that type of cap?

Tags: sewing

The other day, I was watching The Office and noticed Jim's cap. I would like to find the name of that type of cap to make one of my own. Unfortunately, it's near to impossible to find a pattern when you don't know the name of the model you are looking for.

What is the name of the model depicted in the following screenshot?

[image]

To have a better look at it, it's at the end of the 10th episod from the 4th season.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for the identification of an object and has - as such - nothing to do with arts or crafts. Questions like these can be asked in our [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38932/the-studio) if anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [flat cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_cap), colloquially more commonly seen as "newsboy cap" in North America. Other areas will have other common names for it, including (as seen on Wikipedia) "scally cap," "bunnet," "Dai cap," "paddy cap," "cheese-cutter," and "driving cap."

You're most likely to find patterns or instructions under the names "flat cap," "newsboy cap," and "driving cap."

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it goes by several different names:
Beret hunting cap
Driving hunting cap
Gatsby hat

Searched Amazon: Beret hunting cap:
[image]

Gatsby hat on Google search gave these results:
[image]

Hope this gets you in the right direction!